# Rows inside a row MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning to store values into db with PHP
this is what I did:

```
$Sub=array();

  array_push($Sub,$s1,$s2,$s3,$s4,$s5);
  $Subs=implode(",",$Sub);

 print_r($Sub);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname,lastname,contact,pass,email)
    VALUES ('$fname','$lname',$cont,'$pass','$email')";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO sensei (TeacherName,Subjects)
    VALUES ('$fname','".$Subs."')";
```

result:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|id      | Name     | Subjects               |
+--------------------------------------------+
|1       | Osama    | Maths, Chemistry,..... |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

I am an intern and I have been told to do it like this

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|id      | Name     | Subjects               |
+--------------------------------------------+
|        |          | Maths                  |
|1       |  Osama   |------------------------|
|        |          |Chemistry               |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

I am getting values from a form

Can this be done?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: I am just learning

Comment: You cannot store a row in a row, well not in MySQL anyway

Comment: You should look into relations (one to many). Another option is to store a data structure (JSON) in `Subjects`.

Comment: Have you been told to _store_ the data this way, or maybe just to present it in this format when it gets _displayed_ somewhere? Those would be two massively different things.

Comment: Expanding on @nitrin0's comment. You should have another table, such as `sensei_subjects`, with the columns `sensei_id, subject`. Then you can insert `(1, 'Maths')` and `(1, 'Chemistry')`; two rows to indicate that sensei 1 can teach those two subjects.  Though you should really have a `subject` table, where each subject is assigned its own `id`, to avoid storing strings everywhere (these ids are known as surrogate keys).  Also, you probably should take some SQL courses; Stackoverflow isn't suited for teaching the basics or relational design.

Comment: You can explode(",",$row['subjects']), loop through it to display the subjects as like your Subjects column.

Comment: **Never** store multiple values in one column.

Comment: As above, don't do this, read up on "database normalisation" for more detail on this. It'll make it much more difficult to retrieve information, sort by it, produce stats and so on.